# Espresso 2.2.1 - Check if fragment layout is displayed

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

How can I check if fragment is displayed in espresso? Can I use layout id in withId?

```
onView(withId(R.layout.foo_fragment)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I get a no views in hierarchy exception.

Answer (score 6):

R.layout.foo_fragment is not the ID of the root of your fragment; that's the layout ID for inflation.  You should set an ID on the root of your fragment, then do `onView(withId(R.id.fragmentIDname)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`